# Android kotlin - RecyclerView app crash after deleting items in specific order

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

This is the adapter:

```
class ContactsAdapter(val context: Context, private val users: MutableList<Contacts>, val itemClick: (Contacts) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.remove.setOnClickListener {

            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            builder.setMessage(R.string.delete_contact)

            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes){_, _ ->
                users.removeAt(position)
                notifyItemRemoved(position)
            }

            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.no){_,_ ->

            }

            val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
            dialog.show()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = users.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.contacts, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view, itemClick)
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View?, val itemClick: (Contacts) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!){
        val remove = itemView!!.removecontact!!
    }
}
```

I got 2 items for testing, when I delete the second then first one it's fine, but when first then second one then the app crashes and the error is:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:503)
        at com.xxx.xxx.classes.ContactsAdapter$onBindViewHolder$2$1.onClick(ContactsAdapter.kt:57)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:177)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you remove the first item, the second item's position becomes "0" from "1" hence the error.

Comment: That's what I just thought but how to solve this?

Comment: Instead of this: `notifyItemRemoved(position)` try `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Nope same happens

Comment: This will help: `users.removeAt(position)` then `notifyItemRemoved(position)` then `notifyItemRangeChanged(position, users.size());` Try it

Comment: Still crash :/ ..

Comment: Is it the same crash?

Comment: Instead of `position` try `getAdapterPosition()` in those 3 lines.

Comment: This way it works, thank you!

Comment: Which way? you mean `getAdapterPosition()`?

Comment: Yes, like in the accepted answer

Comment: Okay, did you also write this: `notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), users.size());` ?

Comment: No just users.removeAt(holder.adapterPosition) and notifyItemRemoved(holder.adapterPosition)

Comment: Alright then.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see, it is an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because you are attempting to access the index 1 in an array of size 1. This is mostly because you are directly using the `position` argument from `onBindViewHolder` from inside the AlertDialog's `setPositiveButton` call.

Instead use the `holder.getAdapterPosition` method to get the latest position. This should prevent the crash.

**Edit #1**: What I mean is to replace the `position` usages with `holder.getAdapterPosition()`. Your onBindViewHolder should look like this after the edits:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.remove.setOnClickListener {

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        builder.setMessage(R.string.delete_contact)

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes){_, _ ->
            users.removeAt(holder.getAdapterPosition())
            notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition())
        }

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.no){_,_ ->

        }

        val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how? I don't understand all this prebuild stuff

Comment: I tried it right after users.removeAt(position) but still crash

Comment: Updated answer with code. Please try it out and let me know

Comment: thanks i made  this mistake and now my adapter works fine . can you tell what is diffrence between position and holder.adapterposition ? should not they be the same?

Answer (score 0):

> I got 2 items for testing, when I delete the second then first one it's fine, but when first then second one then the app crashes.

My guess is you do not refresh of the indezes of the list Items in your view
When you remove your fist item everything is fine you removed Index 0 from a list of 2
But your second crashes because you try to remove Index 1 (the second item) of a list that only has one element left.

your "notifyItemRemoved(position)" has to reassign the indezes of all the items that are left after removing one

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, set the click listener outside the bindview holder as it is the bad practice. Just set it on onCreateViewHolder. Then, you will come to know that the listener gets called for the first time as soon as the adapter is set. For that you need to stop it from getting called by simply declaring a bool variable and assigning it to false in the adapter class like this.

```
 private var islistenerCalledFirst: Boolean = false;
```

Then in the OnCreateViewHolder set the listener. Note, you can get position of the item by calling viewHolder.getAdapterPosition().

```
  holder.remove.setOnClickListener {

        if(islistenerCalledFirst){
              ... //your logic
        }

        islistenerCalledFirst = true
    }
```

Hope this works for you.